Performance Consideration with `WITH` clause (CTE) and `IN` operator
Previously, I've been using separate code for MySQL and SQLite when using the WITH clause and IN operator. I use IN (TABLE cte) in MySQL and IN cte in SQLite.
After seeing dupes like this, and this, I've got some idea of how to use WITH clause and IN operator portably - use a SELECT clause. Here's what I do right now:
MySQL:
WITH cte AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table1 WHERE ...)
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ... AND ((column1, column2) IN (TABLE cte))
ORDER BY column3

SQLite:
WITH cte AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table1 WHERE ...)
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ... AND ((column1, column2) IN cte)
ORDER BY column3

However, I'm a bit worried about performance. If I do the following:
Portable:
WITH cte AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM Table1 WHERE ...)
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ... AND ((column1, column2) IN (SELECT * FROM cte))
ORDER BY column3

Q1: Would a third select clause (as simple as IN (SELECT * FROM cte)) be burdonsome to execute, if cte was part of the result from the WITH clause? Especially when Table2 is very large?
Q2: For MySQL and SQLite, have they applied any kind of optimization on this?

JOIN with the CTE instead of using IN.

@Barmar Appreciated. I'm not very well-versed in database programming, would you mind making a full answer?

Hi - if you are worried about performance then I'd just run these queries and see what happens. Look at the EXPLAIN PLANs to see how they are actually being executed. As the execution plan (and therefore performance) can change depending on data volumes, indexing, etc. - looking at the basic SQL when considering performance is unlikely to achieve much

Just do it like joining a real table. There's nothing specific to CTE in this question.

@Barmar I did it. Although I've seen selection of rows from "product" of tables in my IT theory book, I've never really wrote any JOIN clause. Thanks!

If you want portability and performance, don't use CTE or IN ( SELECT ... ) or "row constructors".  This probably has better portability and performance:
SELECT table1.*
    FROM Table2
    JOIN table1  USING (column1, column2)
    ORDER BY table1.column3

If USING is not handled everywhere, say
       ON   (table1.column1 = table2.column1 
        AND  table1.column2 = table2.column2) 


Thank you for your response. The MRE is overly simplified from what's in my production environment. I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm able to test and deploy it.

Sometimes simplifying a query leads to a solution that is not relevant.  I hope my suggestion works anyway.

The biggest problem with my simplification was that, there were additional rows from Table2 that's not joinable with Table1, I solve this with LEFT JOIN.
